# OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. While Using Disco Diffusion

Tags: python, google-notebook

While running Disco Diffusion, on the Google notebook, I ran into the following error in "Generate optical flow and consistency maps"

The full error code: OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 508.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.75 GiB total capacity; 13.05 GiB already allocated; 334.81 MiB free; 13.35 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

I looked it up on Google but didn't find any helpful answers, as in, answers I could understand or that provided solutions that made some sense.

Please assume I'm a complete noob when providing with an explanation, because I am.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your program needs to either be optimized or given a smaller batch size. You are literally out of physical memory on your computer and that operation requires more than you've got to work with. If you had beefier hardware it would probably run for a little while longer before eventually running out of memory. If you're trying to do an operation on a large dataset break it up in to smaller bits and have them run one by one and compile in to a finished end result at the end.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you'd elaborate on what to do next, because all of this doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: @FMB Could you provide a code sample in your question. Also is it the terminology you don't understand? Because this is quite literally the solution to the issue you are facing. You're out of memory, code does operations, operations cost memory, less data to process means less memory used.

Comment: Yeah I do have a hard time with the terminology. Ultimately what I ended up doing was upload a lighter file. I have no idea how to provide a sample code.

Comment: Lighter file is essentially a smaller batch size @FMB